# Angular Material Tab : Prevent tab change of mat-tab-group if the form in current tab is dirty

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

I was trying to prevent tab change of `mat-tab`, if the form in currently active tab is dirty.

But I couldn't find a way to intercept the tab change event.

```
<mat-tab-group>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 0" >

    // Tab 0 Content

  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 1"  >

    // Tab 1 Content

  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 2" >

    // Tab 2 Content

  </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Even though there is a `selectedTabChange` event, we can't prevent tab change. we can only switch tab programatically after tab change.

Answer (score 6):

This solution is just a work around and has its flaws. It is mentioned below.

**Steps :**

**In the template** :

1. Disable all tabs of the mat-tab-group
   `<mat-tab label="Tab 0" disabled>`
2. Provide a click event handler on mat-tab-group.
   Also set the `selectedIndex` property using a variable from the component class.

   `<mat-tab-group  (click)="tabClick($event)" [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex">`

**In the Component class** :

1. Declare the variable `selectedTabIndex`
   `selectedTabIndex = 0;`
2. Create a method to get the tab Index , provided the tab label.

   ```
    getTabIndex(tabName: string): number {

    switch (tabName) {
      case 'Tab 0': return 0;
      case 'Tab 1': return 1;
      case 'Tab 2': return 2;
      default: return -1; // return -1 if clicked text is not a tab label text
     }

    }
   ```

   We can get the tab-label text from a property of the click event

   ```
   `clickEventName.toElement.innerText`
   ```
3. Create the method for handling the click event on mat-tab-group.

   ```
    tabClick(clickEvent: any) {

    // Get the index of clicked tab using the above function
    const clickedTabIndex = this.getTabIndex(clickEvent.toElement.innerText);

    // if click was not on a tab label, do nothing
    if (clickedTabIndex === -1) {
      return;
    }

    // if current tab is same as clicked tab, no need to change. 
    //Otherwise check whether editing is going on and decide

    if (!(this.selectedTabIndex === clickedTabIndex)) {

      if ( /*logic for form dirty check*/ ) {

        // if form is dirty, show a warning modal and don't change tab.
      }
      else {

        // if form is not dirty, change the tab
        this.selectedTabIndex = clickedTabIndex;
      }
    }
   ```

   }

In my case each tab content was in separate components. So I used `@ViewChild` to access them and check whether any of the form is dirty or not.

**Flaws** :

1. Since this method uses the text of clicked element for switching tabs, there is a chance that one of your tab may contain some element with text content same as
   the heading of other tabs.

   So it may trigger a tab change. You can look for other properties in click event to prevent this scenario if possible.
   I used following code in `tabClick()` method's beginning

   ```
    if (!((clickEvent.toElement.className).toString().includes('mat-tab-label'))) {
     return;
     }
   ```
2. You may need to override the `css` of `disabled` state of `mat-tab` to make it look natural

**Template** :

```
<mat-tab-group  (click)="tabClick($event)" [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex">

  <mat-tab label="Tab 0" disabled>

    // Tab 0 Content

  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 1"  disabled>

    // Tab 1 Content

  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 2"  disabled>

    // Tab 2 Content

  </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: It would be much useful.. If you can add a stackblitz link of the above solution.

Comment: This works fine in Chrome but getting ERROR TypeError: clickEvent.toElement is undefined in Firefox. can someone please advise how to fix this one?                       // This line is causing the issue
const clickedTabIndex = this.getTabIndex(clickEvent.toElement.innerText);

Comment: not work!!!!!!!