# is there beforeTabChange event in mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm currently working on a forms with several tabs.

I want to prevent user from switching to another tab if the form is dirty.

Is there such an event like `beforeTabChange`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material Tab : Prevent tab change of mat-tab-group if the form in current tab is dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607394/angular-material-tab-prevent-tab-change-of-mat-tab-group-if-the-form-in-curren)

Answer (score 0):

The only `@Output()` events you can bind to according to the [Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup) are

```
@Output() animationDone: EventEmitter<void>
Event emitted when the body animation has completed

@Output() focusChange: EventEmitter<MatTabChangeEvent>
Event emitted when focus has changed within a tab group.

@Output() selectedIndexChange: EventEmitter<number>
Output to enable support for two-way binding on [(selectedIndex)]

@Output() selectedTabChange: EventEmitter<MatTabChangeEvent>   
Event emitted when the tab selection has changed.
```

so you could technically listen to the events on the tab group. but that seems overly complicated.

It might be better to use the `disabled` attribute on the tab to bind to the conditions you wish to use i.e.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab #first label="First" [disabled]="!first.isActive && form.invalid">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab #second label="Second" [disabled]="INSERT CONDITION">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab #second label="Third" [disabled]="INSERT CONDITION">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

you can then bind your template to a value that is maintained in the class. or use template references to disable a tab if it isn't the currently active one and your form is invalid. `!first.isActive && form.invalid`